# Is there a way to know at compile time whether environmental variables exist in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make sure to receive input for safe use of environmental variables in the Flutter app.
Therefore, I want to make sure that the commands of 'flutter run' or 'flutter build' are not executed at runtime, but at compile time. Is there a good way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched through the keyword "static assert" and solved it.
This method fails when dart-define is not provided for build time.

```dart
class StaticAssert {
  const StaticAssert(bool condition, [String message = "Assertion Failed"])
      : assert(condition, message);
}

class DartDefine {
  @StaticAssert(environment == "development" || environment == "production",
      "--dart-define environment=<value> must be one of development or production")
  static const String environment = String.fromEnvironment('environment');
}
```

Comment: Great for you, good job 